# Restoring GeoPackage from exported QField app

Tags: qgis, export, qfield, geopackage

I have created a QGIS project and exported it as an offline-editing app for QField. I packaged the project using the QField Sync plugin and have several point layers (with offline editing) stored into a GeoDatabase

I was playing around with the project and ended up deleting the main GeoDatabase. As a result, every time I try to sync the collected data from the QField app to the QGIS Project, it won't find the original data sources to add the data entries. Of course, this makes sense, because I deleted it.

I was just wondering if it is possible to re-create the original GeoPackage, based on the exported app?

What I mean is exactly as the original data was set up including the Layout forms and the specified default values (like Value Maps etc.).

As an alternative, is it possible to create the original GeoPackage from scratch if I use the same field names?

Or is that only possible if it's exactly the same?

I did manage to recover a .gpkg file and a .gpkg-shm file but those files won't open in QGIS. I'm using QGIS 3.16.5 (Hannover).

Comment: did you export the data from qgis to qfield wie QFieldSync plugin? and did you mark some layers as "offline editable" ?

Comment: Yes, I used the QField Sync plugin, and most layers were set to 'offline editing'

Comment: If you open the data.gpkg from the qfield project in QGIS, can you see all the data?

Comment: Yes, I can still see all the data. My problem is that the layout form in the Attributes Form are back to the default 'Autogenerate'. In the initial database I specified default values for some of the variables, for example Value Maps or a linked csv with the available options.